# unable to edit a document online. Error "Upload Failed the minor version limit has been exceeded"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning, version

Some users has received the following error when they try to edit some documents inside online sharepoint site:-

[image]

now based on my knowledge what we can control inside the document library's versioning settings; is the number of major versions + the number of major versions that have minor versions. but we can not control the number of minor versions for each major version. so how we can fix the above error? i suggest to publish the document to major version so they can get a new number of minor versions.. is this solution valid?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have reached the maximum number of minor versions you will need to publish a major version to continue.

**Version limits:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#versions

**Instructions to publish major version:**

In SharePoint, Click 3 dots for the document > More > Publish > 3 dots > advanced > Major > write a comment on the update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/publish-or-unpublish-a-version-of-a-file-8766f85c-350d-46f3-9a80-42de99aff610

Comment: thanks for the link,, i was expecting that the version limits means that after the 511 minor version sharepoint will remove the older minor version and create a new one instead of raising an error..

Comment: Did the post answer your question?

Comment: The link does not have the instructions on how to publish a major version. For me it was on Sharepoint (online) Right click --> More --> Publish Version and then you can write a comment on the update.